# my code can't go to the next page after scraping the first page using selenium python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping

Can you help me figure why my code didn't go to the next page after scraping the first one?
I tried so much but it seemed i can't figure it out

```
from selenium import webdriver

number = 1
page = 'https://www.olx.com.eg/properties/alexandria/?page={}'.format(number)
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
while number <= 500:
    driver.get(page)
    test = [li.get_attribute('href') for li in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('#offers_table .ads__item__ad--title')]
    for link in test:
        driver.get(link)
        # if driver.find_element_by_css_selector('h1.brkword.lheight28'):
        #     name = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('h1.brkword.lheight28').text
        # else:
        #     name = ''
        # date = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('span.brlefte5').text[26:41]
        # bed_rooms = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('tr:nth-child(1) .col:nth-child(1) a').text
        # bath_rooms = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('tr:nth-child(1) .col+ .col a').text
        # area = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('tr:nth-child(2) .col:nth-child(1) strong').text
        # furnished = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('tr+ tr .col+ .col a').text
        # floor = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#offerdescription > div.clr.descriptioncontent.marginbott20 > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(3) > td.col > table > tbody > tr > td > strong > a').text
        # desc = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#textContent .large').text
        # address = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.c2b').text
        # price = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.not-arranged').text
        try:
            mobile_btn = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#contact_methods > li > div > strong')
            mobile_btn.click()
            mobile = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#contact_methods > li > div > strong').text
        except:
            mobile = 'no mobile found'
        # owner = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.user-box__info__name').text
        print(mobile)
number += 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You code is almost fine, I tested it and it goes through each link from the main page. The problem is that you have the `number += 1` outside the scope of the `while` loop and you dont generate the new URL

```
from selenium import webdriver

number = 1
# Have a variable just for the page URL
page = 'https://www.olx.com.eg/properties/alexandria/?page='
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
while number <= 500:
    # Inside the loop add the page number
    driver.get('{}{}'.format(page, number)
    test = [li.get_attribute('href') for li in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('#offers_table .ads__item__ad--title')]
    for link in test:
        driver.get(link)
        try:
            mobile_btn = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#contact_methods > li > div > strong')
            mobile_btn.click()
            mobile = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#contact_methods > li > div > strong').text
        except:
            mobile = 'no mobile found'
        # owner = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.user-box__info__name').text
        print(mobile)
    number += 1
```

The last line needs to be indented inside the while loop.
If you want to make it in a more pythonic way:

```
for number in range(1, 500):
```

Answer (score 1):

First, wait till the driver can find your button, by simply waiting 
using `driver.implicitly_wait(10)` And after clicking also wait for some time. So that the element containing your text appears.

Comment: you misunderstand my friend the code is for scraping the website but the button is not for clicking the next page it is for scraping phone number that is require a click to show but what i need to is about number and page and number += 1. my idea is after going to each link and scrape the data from it then go to the next page what this code do is go to the first page and scrape the links then go to each link and scrape the data after finishing it goes to the first page again i don't want this

Answer (score 1):

You have just missed the step.you need to define page variable inside while loop before `driver.get(page)` called.What you did you defined it outside while loop.Try now.

```
from selenium import webdriver

number = 1
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
while number <= 500:
    page = 'https://www.olx.com.eg/properties/alexandria/?page={}'.format(number)
    number += 1
    driver.get(page)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all this is the solution

```
from selenium import webdriver

number = 1
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
while number <= 500:
    page = 'https://www.olx.com.eg/properties/alexandria/?page={}'.format(number)
    driver.get(page)
    test = [li.get_attribute('href') for li in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('#offers_table .ads__item__ad--title')]
    for link in test:
        driver.get(link)
        # if driver.find_element_by_css_selector('h1.brkword.lheight28'):
        #     name = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('h1.brkword.lheight28').text
        # else:
        #     name = ''
        # date = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('span.brlefte5').text[26:41]
        # bed_rooms = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('tr:nth-child(1) .col:nth-child(1) a').text
        # bath_rooms = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('tr:nth-child(1) .col+ .col a').text
        # area = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('tr:nth-child(2) .col:nth-child(1) strong').text
        # furnished = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('tr+ tr .col+ .col a').text
        # floor = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#offerdescription > div.clr.descriptioncontent.marginbott20 > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(3) > td.col > table > tbody > tr > td > strong > a').text
        # desc = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#textContent .large').text
        # address = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.c2b').text
        # price = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.not-arranged').text
        # try:
        #     mobile_btn = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#contact_methods > li > div > strong')
        #     mobile_btn.click()
        #     mobile = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#contact_methods > li > div > strong').text
        # except:
        #     mobile = 'no mobile found'
        owner = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.user-box__info__name').text
        print(owner)
        print(page)
        break
    number += 1
```